# Access variables from another file

Tags: php, include

I'm trying to have something like a configuration file, and store in it variables.
When I'm trying to include it, I can't access the variables. it gives me this error:
`Notice: Undefined variable: myVar`

---

`include.php`

```
<?php
$myVar = "Text";
?>
```

---

`index.php`

```
<?php
include('include.php');
?>
<html>
.....
<body>
<?php
echo $myVar;
?>
</body>
```

---

P.S. I heard it's not a good habit to have this file with variables and include it in every page. if it is, please show me the better way to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Apart from the fact that `echo $myVar` is not in a `<?php ?>` block, this should work just fine.

Comment: You should echoed `$myVar;` in `<?php ?>` block

Comment: @deceze, you're right... but how he got message `Notice: Undefined variable: myVar`. This is notice from PHP, right?... and obviously line `echo $myVar` has not been executed as PHP code. Maybe I'm wrong but HTML outputs this line as is.

Comment: Maybe care to post the whole Notice, including the line number and file (or investigate yourself based on that information)?

Comment: @deceze, maybe but he said `it gives me this error`... and this piece of code doesn't throw anything, just outputs `echo $myVar;` in browser as text ;)

Comment: @deceze It was a mistake due to a rush (I had to go somewhere), my bad. anyways, it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're thinking about using include.php to use as a database sort of, then I'ld suggest reading about MySQL and start using that instead.
If you're only looking to carry on a single variable, your code should be all right.

I don't know if it's just your message, or if you do the same in your code, but echo $myVar must be inside a php tag

```
<?php echo $myVar; ?>
```

Also, make sure you've entered the correct path to your file in the include() function, and make sure it's called before trying to output the variable.

Comment: Put `echo $myVar;` between BODY tags like he did and tell me does it throw `Notice: Undefined variable: myVar`?

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5 Where did I say that alone was the cause of the error? I just pointed out everything that was wrong, and might be wrong with what he gave us to look at. But since he didn't echo myVar anywhere else, you do have a point

Comment: Sure, you're absolutely right but putting that PHP part inside PHP tags or leaving that between BODY tags, doesn't throw notice like he said. I didn't downvoted your answer just pointed out that this line `echo $myVar` is not a reason for notice he got. Obviously he has something more in code (we dont see from this chunk) which throws that notice.